# Package xkeyval Error: valign undefined in families Gin

Tags: graphics

I fond this example on this site:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\newenvironment{centerentry}[2][]
  {\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{##1}}
   \noindent
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{ @{} m{\imagecolwidth} X @{} }
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1]{#2} &
  }{%
   \endtabularx%
  }
\newlength{\imagecolwidth}
\setlength{\imagecolwidth}{2em}

\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{centerentry}{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\begin{centerentry}[height=5em]{symbols/symbol_q.PNG}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{centerentry}

\end{document}
```

If I use this construct:

```
\begin{centerentry}{symbols/Mouse.PNG} Text: \includegraphics[height=8ex,valign=c]{images/Copy.PNG}
\end{centerentry}
```

I get:

! Package xkeyval Error: `valign' undefined in families`Gin'.

Someone ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 20):

`\includegraphics` does not by default have a `valign` key.

If you use the `adjustbox` package with option `export` then that package adds `valign`

Comment: For anyone having the same problem but not necessarily understanding what @David Carlisle meant by "using the `adjustbox` package with `export` option" (like myself).
`\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`