# Align images to the middle but cannot use valign or packages not accepted by ACM TAPS

Tags: tables, graphics, includegraphics

I have a table containing images. The `valign=m` ensures that the images are centered in the middle. However, for the valign to work correctly, I have to use the `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` as suggested by a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397708/package-xkeyval-error-valign-undefined-in-families-gin) on Stack.  ACM TAPS does not like people including extra packages, so [all the packages not part of ACM need to be removed](https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages).

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3em}}c@{\hspace{3.5em}}c}
\hline
\textbf{Level} & \textbf{Screenshot}                                      & \textbf{A Sample Solution}                                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline  \\[-8pt]
1             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1.5em]{sampleteaser} \\  \\[-8pt]
2             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1.5em]{sampleteaser} \\  \\[-8pt]
3             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1.5em]{sampleteaser} \\  \\[-8pt]
4             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1em]{sampleteaser} \\  \\[-8pt]
5             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=2.2em]{sampleteaser} \\  \\[-8pt]
6             & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=5em]{sampleteaser} & \includegraphics[valign=m,height=1.5em]{sampleteaser}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Levels 1 through 6}
\label{tab:MazzyLevels1}
\end{table}
```

[image: Pic with valign=m looks centered. Ignore the overflow that's a different issue]

Because of ACM restrictions, I had to remove the `valign=m` which defaults to bottom alignment. While it doesn't look so bad here, the actual image with the tables can be confusing to the readers.

[image: Pic without valign=m. The alignment is no longer there.]

I'm looking for a solution that aligns the images to center using only packages that are a part of ACM accepted list of packages. I would appreciate any help you can give me here.

Comment: `\raisebox{-2.5em}{includegraphics[height=5em]{sampleteaser} }`

Comment: One could argue that graphicx and adjustbox are actually one package split into two parts, sort of like caption and subcaption.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I think this is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox{-2.5em}{includegraphics[height=5em]{sampleteaser}}`